# 全角英文字のタグ名を認める？

Tags: 討議, タグ

タグ[html](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) に対する タグ[ｈｔｍｌ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%ef%bd%88%ef%bd%94%ef%bd%8d%ef%bd%8c)のように、いわゆる全角英文字で構成されたタグ名を作る（認める）べきでしょうか？

例に挙げた[ｈｔｍｌ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%ef%bd%88%ef%bd%94%ef%bd%8d%ef%bd%8c)の場合、[タグ シノニム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)は設定されていないようです。本ケースは、[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)/[algorithm](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)のような"別名"とも異なりますし、シノニム機能が相応しいとも思えませんでした。"ruby"に対して"ｒｕｂｙ"を用意するのか？のように、際限がなくなる点も懸念しています。

**追記**：下記ページのタグWiki部分で気付いたのですが、Stack Overflowのシステム的には中途半端に同一視しているようです。個別のタグとして扱っていますが、タグ情報は[同一ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info)へリダイレクトされます。

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/html/
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/%EF%BD%88%EF%BD%94%EF%BD%8D%EF%BD%8C/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

私がそのようなタグを見かけたら、その場で正しいタグに修正して、それでおしまいです。

> 間違ったタグまたは正しくないタグ、または同じことを意味する複数のｎタグが繰り返しつけられる質問を見かけたら、タグの別名を提案するとよいでしょう。目的は、一般的なタグの間違いについて、再タグ付けを自動化することで手動の再タグ付けタスクを省略することです。
>   <sub>--- [ヘルプ センター > 権限 > タグの別名の作成](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) より引用</sub>

上記の説明からも、同じようなタグの付け間違いが**今後も頻繁に予想され**、それを**個別のルールなしには判別できない**場合にのみ、タグの別名（シノニム）を使えばいいと思います。

- どちらの呼称も広く使われている： [cpp](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpp) → [c++](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
- メインタグは正式名称にしたい： [rails](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails) → [ruby-on-rails](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)
- メインタグは日本語にしたい：[algorithm](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) → [アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)

稀に起きる分には見かけた人が手動で付け直せば済みますし、なんとなればシステム側で（サジェスト時に？）全角英数字を一括で半角英数字に置き換えてもいいと思います。

Comment: +1: 最初は"ｈｔｍｌ"タグを消して終わろうと思ったのですが、今後も類似パターンが起こりうるかなと思ってメタ投稿してみました。（該当タグはすでに消えているようですね）