# 全角英数字をタグに使えないようにしてほしい

Tags: バグ, 機能の要求, 延期, タグ

投稿画面の説明ではタグについて「漢字・ひらがな・カタカナおよび半角英数字と # - . が使えます」とありますが、実際には全角英数字も使えてしまっています。

今のところ頻度は少ないので手作業で修正していますが、できればシステム側でエラーにするか半角英数字に変換していただけると、手間が省けて助かります。

参考 [全角英文字のタグ名を認める？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/8000)

具体的には記号も含め、ASCII文字が存在する U+FF01 ～ U+FF5E は全て禁止でいいかと。

Unicodeプロパティ等でひらがな・カタカナ・漢字に限定してもいいですが。

Comment: これがかなり治しにくいです。SQLとC#の文字の使い方が異なるため、このような問題が発生します。2年以上前に治そうとしましたが、現在大幅なコード変更をしないとかんたんにはできませんらしいです。もう一回開発者とフォローしますが、同じ結果になると思います。

Comment: これがなかなか直らないので、MSE の方に改善をお願いする投稿をしてみました。現在 status-review 状態となっています。 [Please avoid creation of tags with full-width alphanumeric characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343575/341401)

Comment: 本件を確認し、バックログに追加しました。タグを [延期] に付け替えました。