# タグの全角英数字を禁止するルールを追加したい

Tags: 機能の要求, タグ, ブロックリスト

[「全角英数字をタグに使えないようにしてほしい」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2405) で出されている要望を実現するため、ブロックリストに下記の項目を追加して下さい。

- Type: Tag
- Pattern: `[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]+` (Note that these are not ASCII characters, but their [fullwidth forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block)).)
- Match Action: Block
- Message: `タグ名には全角の英数字を使わずに、半角の英数字（<code>a-z</code>、<code>0-9</code>）を使用して下さい（全角であっても、漢字やカタカナなどの日本語は使用できます）。`

上記設定は、まずメタサイトに設定していただいて、問題ないことがユーザー側で確認された後に、メインサイトにも適用して下さい。

---

#### 正規表現の説明

- 記号は考慮しない: 全角記号の排除は、既に全サイト的に実装済みのようですので、ここでは含めません。
- `+`: マッチ箇所がブロック時にメッセージの一部として表示される可能性が有るため、1字のマッチで十分とせず、`+` を使用しています。こういった詳細は、はっきり解っていないのでメタサイトでのテスト時に確認し、調整したいと思います。

#### 要望する理由

全角英数字のタグが作成されることは非常に稀であり、必ずしもシステム側で対応する必要は無いと思います。しかし、今回は下記の理由で依頼することにしました。端的に言うと、動きが怪しすぎて放置したくない、ということです。

##### 未知、あるいは新規のバグを回避する

例えば現時点では、付与された全角英数タグの半角バージョンが存在する場合、その半角バージョンも同時に付与されるというバグが有ります。このバグには便利な面もありますが、意図されたもので無い以上、今後のアップデートではどのような振舞いになるのか、予想がつきません。

このような現象がいたずらに発生していることは問題です。他にも、見えない箇所で何か問題が生じている、あるいはこれから生じる可能性が有ります。こういったバグを事前に回避できるなら、するのが良いと考えます。

##### ユーザーが奇妙な現象に遭遇するのを防ぐ

全角英数タグの振舞いには奇妙な点が多々有り、遭遇したユーザーの時間を奪います。事前にブロックされてメッセージが出る方が、結局は理解が早く、ユーザーの時間が無駄にならないと考えます。

##### 回避策が有るなら、それを選択する

ブロックリストによる対処は、理想的な解決では無く、妥協的な回避策です。

全角英数字に対する最も適切な対応は、全角英数字を対応する半角英数字に自動で置き換えることでしょう。しかし、こういった日本語版独自の実装の要望がStack Exchange社に受け入れられた例を私は知りません。回避策が有る場合はそれを選択し、新規実装が必要な事柄は、どうしても必要なものに限って要望するのが良いと考えます。

Comment: 本件は改めて細かく議論する必要は無いかも知れないと考えたため、設定値は最初から私の案を書きました。
修正案やご意見をしばらく待った後、Stack Exchange社にエスカレーションするつもりです。

Comment: +1: メッセージとしては関係しているのは英数字だけなので記号はメッセージから除いてしまって良さそうです。

Comment: 確かに関係無いので、記号の部分（`+ # - .`）はメッセージから削除しました。