# タグシノニムの提案: 深層学習 ← deep-learning

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

現在 [deep-learning](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) と [深層学習](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e6%b7%b1%e5%b1%a4%e5%ad%a6%e7%bf%92) が共に存在します。
これは翻訳の差なので、タグシノニムの設定を提案します。

[deep-learning](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) の方が投稿数が多いですが、[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2044/19110)によるとメインタグは日本語にする習慣があるようなので、 [深層学習](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e6%b7%b1%e5%b1%a4%e5%ad%a6%e7%bf%92) をメインタグにするのが良いと思います。

Comment: 別に投稿した方が良いのかもしれませんが、「機械学習」と「machine-learning」も共存してますね...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

以下のタグシノニムを作成いたしました。

- [深層学習](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e6%b7%b1%e5%b1%a4%e5%ad%a6%e7%bf%92) ← [deep-learning](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning)
- [機械学習](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e6%a9%9f%e6%a2%b0%e5%ad%a6%e7%bf%92) ← [machine-learning](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning)