# 英語タグから日本語タグへのシノニムを作りたい

Tags: 討議, タグ

[深層学習](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e6%b7%b1%e5%b1%a4%e5%ad%a6%e7%bf%92) と [deep-learning](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) が[共存していた](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2538/19110)際に日本語タグをメインタグにしたように、現状の日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでは日本語タグを優先する緩いルールがあります。

たとえば「カタカナで表されるようなタグ名を、カタカナと英語、どちらで登録すべきか」に対する[entoさんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1385/19110)でも「普通名詞は、日本語表記を優先する」と書かれています。

そこで調べてみたところ、以下のように英語タグが存在することが分かりました。 **これらのタグに対して日本語訳のタグを追加し、メインタグとしてシノニム設定することは妥当でしょうか？**　更に、可能であればそうしたいです。

数が多いため個別に議論が生まれるかと思いますが、その場合も個別に回答や別質問の形でご意見頂ければ幸いです。

以下、私が見つけることのできた英語タグと、その和訳案の一覧です。

- 対応する英語タグと日本語タグが別個に共存しているもの

  - [array](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) / [配列](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e9%85%8d%e5%88%97)
- 普通名詞で、日本語訳もよく使われているが、英語タグしか存在しないもの

  - カタカナでない訳語が存在するもの

    - [video](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video) / 動画、[lambda](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) / ラムダ式、[notification](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notification) / 通知、[exception](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception) / 例外、[audio](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) / 音声
  - そのままカタカナになるもの (-ing系含む)

    - [security](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security) / セキュリティ、[batch-file](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) / バッチファイル、[web-scraping](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) / webスクレイピング、[font](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font) / フォント、[socket](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket) / ソケット、[templates](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates) / テンプレート、[preprocessor](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preprocessor) / プリプロセッサー、 [memory-leaks](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-leaks) / メモリリーク、[console](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console) / コンソール、[shell](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) / シェル、[debugging](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging) / デバッグ、[mail](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mail) / メール、[protocol](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol) / プロトコル、[monitoring](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) / モニタリング、[encoding](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding) / エンコード、[decode](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decode) / デコード、[tagging](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagging) / タギング、[coding-style](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) / コーディングスタイル、[model](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model) / モデル、[mock](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mock) / モック
- 固有名詞だが、和訳の方が良く使われていそうなもの

  - [google-spreadsheet](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) / googleスプレッドシート、[thai](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thai) / タイ語

Comment: 和訳のリストを提供すると、シノニムは作成します。

Comment: @jmac ありがとうございます。とりあえず和訳案を追加しました。しばらく待って賛成票が集まり次第、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

私は翻訳としてカタカナ語しか無い語は、英語のままでいいと思います。

Comment: どちらでも、あまり困る事はないと思いますから、それほど強く主張するものでは無いです。
一応、反対票の入れ先も必要かと思いましたので回答いたしました。

Answer (score 2):

基本的にはmjyさんの見解に同意するのですが、カタカナ語であってもbatch-file / バッチファイルなどは後者の方がいいかなぁと感じますし、カタカナ語でなくともexception / 例外などは前者でいいだろうという気もします。

大半は英語タグしか使われてないのですから、機械的に対応する必要性があるのかという点で疑問があります。

Comment: 英語が分かる方々には今のままでも良いと思うのですが、そうでない方々が意外といそうだと思い、提案してみました。今日本語タグが存在しないタグは、なかなか「じゃあ新しく日本語タグを作って付け替えよう、流行ればシノニムにしよう」とはならないと思いまして……。

Comment: 重複する日本語タグが存在しないのは英語で十分だからだと思います。