# タグ [video] と [動画] をマージしたい

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案

[video](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video) と [動画](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e5%8b%95%e7%94%bb) の二つが存在することに気が付きました。

現状では video タグの付いた投稿の方が多いですが、類似のケースだと以下の様に日本語がマスターになっているので、個人的には "動画" でいいのかなあと思っています。

[image](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image) (別名) -> [画像](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e7%94%bb%e5%83%8f) (マスター)

タグの別名を用意するなら、どちらを優先すべきかご意見があればコメントや回答をください。

関連:
[英語タグから日本語タグへのシノニムを作りたい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2542)

Comment: 「類似のケースだと以下の様に日本語がマスターになっている」←こちら類似のタグとしては何を想定されていますか？　過去に[全部日本語にしたい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2542/19110)という提案を出したら、むしろ英語のほうが良いという話になったことがありまして……。

Comment: 「画像」と「動画」で同じメディアファイル、というくくりのつもりで "類似" の例として挙げました。配列 -> array などもあるのでルール決めが難しいですが。 / 綴りが難しい単語じゃないので、英語のままでもいいかなとも。

Comment: なるほど。個人的には日本語にしたいです。

Comment: 反対が無さそうなので、対応予定といたします。一週間程度、追加の意見を待った後に作業します。

Answer (score 4):

動画をマスター（本名）にする提案に賛成です。

---

コメントで触れられている、

> むしろ英語のほうが良いという話になった

というのは[過去の私の回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2545/3054)を指しているかも知れません。しかし、私の考えをこのケースで言うと、

> 「ビデオ」にする位ならば、「video」のままでよいのでは無いか

というものであり、普及した「動画」という日本語を使用するこのケースには当て嵌らないので、大丈夫です。

---

追記(2023-12-12): マージと別名の設定を完了しました。